# implementation of Agora signalling to communicate when app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, communication, agora.io

I am currently working on **Agora.io** services which give us

> audio,video,one-to-one and broadcast communication

I have successfully implemented these with the help of there given samples, and successfully add signalling module. 
Problem is that signalling call must be active to access all features of it now I want to access all features of signalling at the time when app is closed like whatsapp and other these type of application one solution is make a service of signalling class but this is not professional solution.

I want efficient one solution

Comment: Did you get a solution to this. If so, can you share your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with any 3rd party APIs. This is a system level functionality offered by Apple & Google. You will have to use CallKit (for iOS) or ConnectionService (for Android) to achieve this functionality.

Comment: ConnectionService is inbuilt service?

Comment: Yup it is a Android library

Answer (score 2):

I have done exactly the same thing a few days ago.

For iOS, you have use PushKit and CallKit in the following ways:-

.1. Enable background mode and also check voip.

[image: You dont have to check Audio option necessarily]

2. Import Pushkit and implement PKPushRegistryDelegate functions.

Register pushkit like this :-

```
  func registerPushkitToken() -> Void {
        pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry.init(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        pushRegistry?.delegate = self
        pushRegistry?.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
    }
```

3.Implement the token fuction

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: 
     PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {

let tokenChars = pushCredentials.token.hexString()
 }
```

4. Implement the following function for parsing notification

   func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
   if let userInfo = payload.dictionaryPayload["userInfo"] as? [AnyHashable:Any]{
   }
   }
5. Implement provider delegate functions:

   let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: appName)
               providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
               providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
               providerConfiguration.maximumCallGroups = 1
               providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]

Implement CXProviderDelegate functions

```
func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        print("Function: \(#function), line: \(#line)")

        sessionPool.removeAll()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {

        print("Function: \(#function), line: \(#line)")

        guard let session = pairedSession(of:action.callUUID) else {
            action.fail()
            return
        }

        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = action.handle
        callUpdate.hasVideo = true
        callUpdate.localizedCallerName = callDetails.dispalyName;
        callUpdate.supportsDTMF = false
        provider.reportCall(with: action.callUUID, updated: callUpdate)

        delegate?.callCenter(self, startCall: session)
        action.fulfill()
    }
```

You can also refer to my post here. [how to integrate Callkit with Agora VOiP in swift 4 iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197721/how-to-integrate-callkit-with-agora-voip-in-swift-4-ios/54647666#54647666)