# how to integrate Callkit with Agora VOiP in swift 4 iOS?

Tags: iphone, swift3, callkit, agora.io

I want to integrate apple Callkit with Agora VOiP in swift 4 iOS.

Please give any suggestions How can I do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As written, this question is too broad and open-ended. "Integrate" can mean a lot of things, and it's hard to distinguish this question from a request for a very large amount of free code. You need to narrow this to a specific problem you'e encountered that can be answered with a canonical answer. I recommend starting here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/

Answer (score 8):

To integrate voip, you will have to use both, callKit and PushKit.

**CallKit will be used to show native call screen and handlers during in call transition while Pushkit will be used to invoke app, when app is killed.**

**Its easy to integrate**:-

Enable background modes in info.plist and check option "App provides Voice over IP services".
Import Callkit in the viewcontroller viewdidload/ any init method of anyclass you would use to Implement CXProviderDelegate functions. Through this you will configure call objects, when to report in comming call, accept actions, reject action etc.

Implement the following functions:

```
func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    action.fulfill()
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
    action.fulfill()
}
```

**Now import Pushkit and implement PKPushRegistryDelegate functions.**

a.)Configure pushkit like this

```
let registry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
        registry.delegate = self
        registry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
```

b.) implement pushkit token function. You may have to update to server for delivering voip push notifications

```
 func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        print(pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined())
    }
```

c. Now when you receive incomming notification, implement this fuction

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "App name")
        config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "any image name")!)
        
        config.supportsVideo = true;
        let provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Caller name")
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { error in })
    }
```

4. Go to developer portal and generate VoIP Services certificate and install it.
5. Enable push notifications under Capabilities.

This was a basic code over view. You will have to add cases to simulating incomming call and other customizations. I hope this will help you to move further.

Comment: i integrate agora.io in one of my application. and handle application state using firebase notification. but when my application is killed and received notification that time calling screen is not invoked.

Comment: Please make sure that you are using Pushkit for registering device token. Check for the device tokens, you would have different device tokens for push notifications and VOIP notifications. Also, make sure you are reporting incoming calls in case of receiving VOIP notifications using CXProvider before completion of the didReceiveIncomingPushWith() function, otherwise since iOS 13, the system wont show your calls. Its mandatory to use CallKit with Pushkit or system wont show any calls and even might block VOIP messages on the device.

Comment: i implement push kit . but i have one query where i upload that voip certificate .p12 for notification

Comment: @Protocol Do you know where to upload p12 certificate for VoIP iOS?

Comment: @ShanmugarajeshwaranR Please check link  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit

Comment: @Protocol Thanks for your solution. Currently, I'm facing the issue of connecting Agorasdk on the app's killed state. I have integrated the call kit through VoIP push notification. So, I can receive calls on the app killed state. But I don't know how to connect the AgoraSDK on a Closed sate. Can you help me?

Comment: @ShanmugarajeshwaranR on receiving push notification app wake up and on that event you can connect to the agora server. you can write code on that push notification delegate method for connecting to the agora server.